# PHPUnit handle exception wihtout message in tests

Tags: php, exception, phpunit

In one of my unit tests I have

```
try {
    throw (new UserInputException())->setUserMessage("--redacted--");
} catch (UserErrorException $exception) {
    $exceptionMessage = $exception->getUntranslatedMessage();

    $this->fail("A UserErrorException was thrown with message: $exceptionMessage");
}
```

UserInputException is one of our own classes and the exception is handled by our framework. The problem is a message is not set on it in the normal way, so when the exception is raised in the unit test it's raised without a message.

My quesiton is, is it possible to always catch this particular type of exception in every test like I do here inside one test?

Comment: If you are planning on catching the exception on every test (and the test is not testing if the exception is been thrown) then you are doing something wrong/your code is wrong... why is this happening ?

Comment: 1. I think using try/catch block in a unit test would be an anti-pattern. So it would be good idea to don't do that. 2. can you share your exception code with us, maybe the problem is there. 3. may I ask which framework do you use?

Comment: I agree it's an anti-pattern, hence my question. The exception only is thrown when the case this unit test is written for, goes wrong. We use Slim! 2 framework but this unit test doesn't use the framework at all, that's part of the problem, I'm trying to test an exception that get caught by the framework but am testing it without the framework, to just 1 function itself.